# Al aplicar SSL el sitio se distorsiona. "Conexión no segura: "Partes de esta página no son seguras""

Tags: html, css, certificado-ssl

Hola buenos días estoy colocando el SSL a un sitio web pero cuando agrego el archivo .htacces con el código correspondiente si aplica el SSL, pero  el sitio web se distorsiona. Localice el archivo index.php para sustituir el http por https pero al abrir el index.php me encontré con que tiene las siguientes rutas las cuales no entiendo.

> Código del index.php

```js
<?php
/**
 * User Dashboard Administration Screen
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Administration
 * @since 3.1.0
 */

/** Load WordPress Administration Bootstrap */
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/admin.php' );

require( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/index.php' );
```

> .htaccess

```js
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?raben\.com.mx
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.raben.com.mx/$1 [R,L]
```

> Error en SSL y página distorsionada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Comment: A que te refieres con "se distorsiona", ?

Comment: La página se desacomoda, se mueven las imágenes de posición por ejemplo los iconos de redes sociales deberían de estar al lado del teléfono.

Comment: Estás linkeando estilos y scripts via https y El browser los bloquea, por eso se descuadra. Aplica CTRL+U y busca HTTP://

Comment: ¿En todos los documentos que tiene el sitio web debo de buscar el http://?

Comment: Si se trata de un wordpress, tiene una serie de plugins que fuerzan el uso de https en aquellos recursos que no usan https, de esta formas te ahorras buscar y reemplazar por todos lados, pero a mi me ocurrió una vez algo parecido y tube que reemplazar masivamente en la base de datos http por https de todas formas porque algunos recursos no se veían bien forzando desde plugins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si tu página se desacomoda y se muestra de forma diferente a como se visualizaba después de realizar el cambio a `SSL`, es porque **ahora debes usar páginas y recursos que deben ser cifrados, todos deben usar el protocolo `https://`**, de otra forma habrá elementos como archivos .css, .js o imágenes los cuales no podrán cargarse y eso influirá en el funcionamiento o visualización de tu página.

De hecho puedes ver el mensaje que indica:

> "Partes de esta página no son seguras"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

( En inglés:

> ''Parts of this page are not secure'' and "This page includes other
>   resources which are not secure"

)

**Solución:**

> Para resolver este problema, asegúrese de que el código de la página
>   no extraiga datos directamente de una URL no segura. Ver el código
>   fuente HTML de la página para verificar si hay elementos no seguros.
>   Esto se puede hacer en un navegador web haciendo clic derecho y
>   seleccionando 'ver fuente'. Para identificar elementos no seguros, vea
>   el código fuente de la página y busque el texto src = "http: // Esto
>   resaltará los elementos en su página que se cargan desde una URL no
>   segura. El código fuente (HTML) debe se debe verificar si hay
>   etiquetas NO SEGURAS (es decir, `<img src = "http://www.symantec.com/images/seals/Secure ...">`) Asegúrese de que las
>   siguientes referencias se cambien a HTTPS o un directorio virtual.

---

Revisando tu página, efectivamente puedes ver que **algunos .css están siendo bloqueados ya que están usando `http://` y no `https://`**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debes revisar los archivos que hacen referencia a estos recursos y que se encuentran en el mismo dominio, cambia el protocolo a `https://`.

El archivo que debes editar es `style.css`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya le coloque la s a los archivos css a los cuales hacen referencia el error y ya se acomoda todo en su lugar solo que me sigue marcando el error en el SSL, una disculpa por las molestias  ya que me confundo un poco al migrar páginas que son desarrolladas de otra forma.